# WEBRTC remote video stops streaming after 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, webrtc

I am facing a very weird behavior with this WEBRTC peer to peer app. the app would stream audio form one peer to the other, but when it comes to stream video, it actually stream video but just for the first 2 seconds, then it would stop streaming video, but the audio continues to stream. Here is some of the code that handles the remote video:

```
var webrtc_capable = true;
var rtc_peer_connection = null;
var rtc_session_description = null;
var get_user_media = null;
var connect_stream_to_src = null;
var stun_server = null;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) { 
  rtc_peer_connection = RTCPeerConnection;
  rtc_session_description = RTCSessionDescription;
  get_user_media = navigator.getUserMedia.bind(navigator);
  connect_stream_to_src = function(media_stream, media_element) {
    media_element.srcObject = window.URL.createObjectURL(media_stream);
    media_element.play();
  };
} else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { 
  rtc_peer_connection = mozRTCPeerConnection;
  rtc_session_description = mozRTCSessionDescription;
  get_user_media = navigator.mozGetUserMedia.bind(navigator);
  connect_stream_to_src = function(media_stream, media_element) {
    media_element.srcObject = window.URL.createObjectURL(media_stream);
    media_element.play();
  };
  stun_server = null;
} else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { 
  rtc_peer_connection = webkitRTCPeerConnection;
  rtc_session_description = RTCSessionDescription;
  get_user_media = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia.bind(navigator);
  connect_stream_to_src = function(media_stream, media_element) {
    media_element.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(media_stream);
  };
} else {
  alert("This browser does not support WebRTC - visit WebRTC.org for more info");
  webrtc_capable = false;
}
</script>
<script>


var call_token; 
var signaling_server; 
var peer_connection; 

function start() {
  // create the WebRTC peer connection object
  peer_connection = new rtc_peer_connection({ 
    "iceServers": [ // information about ice servers
      { "url": "stun:"+stun_server }, 
    ]
  });

  // generic handler that sends any ice candidates to the other peer
  peer_connection.onicecandidate = function (ice_event) {
    console.log(ice_event.candidate);
    if (ice_event.candidate){
      console.log("true");
    }
    if (ice_event.candidate) {
      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          token:call_token,
          type: "new_ice_candidate",
          candidate: ice_event.candidate ,
        })
      );
    }
  };


  peer_connection.onaddstream = function (event) {
    var video = document.querySelector("#remote_video");

    video.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(event.stream);

    document.getElementById("loading_state").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("open_call_state").style.display = "block";
  };



  setup_video();


  signaling_server = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1234");

  if (document.location.hash === "" || document.location.hash === undefined) { 


    var token = Date.now()+"-"+Math.round(Math.random()*10000);
    call_token = "#"+token;


    document.location.hash = token;

    signaling_server.onopen = function() {

      signaling_server.onmessage = caller_signal_handler;


      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({ 
          token:call_token,
          type:"join",
        })
      );
    }

    document.title = "You are the Caller";
    document.getElementById("loading_state").innerHTML = "Ready for a call...ask your friend to visit:<br/><br/>"+document.location;

  } else { // you have a hash fragment so you must be the Callee 

    // get the unique token for this call from location.hash
    call_token = document.location.hash;

    signaling_server.onopen = function() {
      // setup caller signal handler
      signaling_server.onmessage = callee_signal_handler;

      // tell the signaling server you have joined the call 
      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({ 
          token:call_token,
          type:"join",
        })
      );

      // let the caller know you have arrived so they can start the call
      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({ 
          token:call_token,
          type:"callee_arrived",
        })
      );
    }

    document.title = "You are the Callee";
    document.getElementById("loading_state").innerHTML = "One moment please...connecting your call...";
  }

  // setup message bar handlers
  document.getElementById("message_input").onkeydown = send_chat_message;
  document.getElementById("message_input").onfocus = function() { this.value = ""; }
}



// handler to process new descriptions
function new_description_created(description) {
  peer_connection.setLocalDescription(
    description, 
    function () {
      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          token:call_token,
          type:"new_description",
          sdp:description 
        })
      );
    }, 
    log_error
  );
}

// handle signals as a caller
function caller_signal_handler(event) {
  var signal = JSON.parse(event.data);
  if (signal.type === "callee_arrived") {
    peer_connection.createOffer(
      new_description_created, 
      log_error
    );
  } else if (signal.type === "new_ice_candidate") {
    peer_connection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.candidate));
  } else if (signal.type === "new_description") {
    peer_connection.setRemoteDescription(
      new rtc_session_description(signal.sdp), 
      function () {
        if (peer_connection.remoteDescription.type == "answer") {
          peer_connection.createOffer(new_description_created, log_error);
        }
      },
      log_error
    );
  } else if (signal.type === "new_chat_message") {
    add_chat_message(signal);
  } else {
    // extend with your own signal types here
  }
}

// handle signals as a callee
function callee_signal_handler(event) {
  var signal = JSON.parse(event.data);
  if (signal.type === "new_ice_candidate") {
    peer_connection.addIceCandidate(
      new RTCIceCandidate(signal.candidate)
    );
  } else if (signal.type === "new_description") {
    peer_connection.setRemoteDescription(
      new rtc_session_description(signal.sdp), 
      function () {
        if (peer_connection.remoteDescription.type == "offer") {
          peer_connection.createAnswer(new_description_created, log_error);
        }
      },
      log_error
    );
  } else if (signal.type === "new_chat_message") {
    add_chat_message(signal);
  } else {
    // extend with your own signal types here
  }
}

// add new chat message to messages list
function add_chat_message(signal) {
  var messages = document.getElementById("messages");
  var user = signal.user || "them"; 
  messages.innerHTML = user+": "+signal.message+"<br/>\n"+messages.innerHTML;
}

// send new chat message to the other browser
function send_chat_message(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var new_message = this.value;
    this.value = ""; 
    signaling_server.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        token:call_token,
        type: "new_chat_message",
        message: new_message 
      })
    );
    add_chat_message({ user: "you", message: new_message }); 
  }
}

// setup stream from the local camera 
function setup_video() {
  get_user_media(
    { 
      "audio": true, // request access to local microphone
      "video": true  // request access to local camera
    }, 
    function (local_stream) { 
      <video> MediaElement

      connect_stream_to_src(local_stream, document.getElementById("local_video"));

      peer_connection.addStream(local_stream);
    },
    log_error
  );
}


function log_error(error) {
  console.log(error);
}

</script>
```

Additional Info:

- Windows 8 x64
- opera version is 27.0.1689.76
- Localvideo plays fine
- This call is between two peers on the same network(no nat traversal)

Comment: This is interesting...What OS? What version of Opera? Is this just a local call(in the same network)? Does the localstream continue to stream just fine in the local_video element?

Comment: my operating system is windows 8 64 bits, opera version is 27.0.1689.76 and it's a local call, i am using localhost. I forgot to mention that the stream from the local peer is showing up in the local_video. But as i said, the remote video element shows live video from the remote peer during the first two seconds and then it just freezes with the last frame.

Comment: Does it happen in Chrome on your system using the same code(prefixes for methods may need to change)?

Comment: Well... in chrome it does not even ask the permission to access the camera, in Firefox the local_stream and sound works but the remote video element shows a black screen. It's worth mentioning that i am using a code from a  book i bought called "Getting started with WebRTC" by Rob Menson. I would like to share the entire code with you, so you might be able to help me out, i've been stuck for a while.

Comment: If Chrome doesn't ask for Camera permission, 2 things: 

1. check that every function is correctly prefixed
2. check on the right side of you URL bar if there is not a red-crossed camera icon. Chrome sometimes defaults to deny access to camera on non HTTPS domain.

It's important you try your code with Chrome. A first educated-guess for your video problem is that your browser doesn't transmit a [**key-frame**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_frame). I think Chrome doesn't suffer from that problem anymore, hence the try. Besides to "verify" my theory, let the app run for several minutes.

Comment: @nschoe i let the app run for several minutes as you told me and i noticed that the remote stream would play a single frame after some time then i waited for some more time and another single frame was played... What could this be?

Comment: Sounds like the encoding in Opera is screwed up...only playing keyframes.

Comment: Any idea how can i fix it ?

Comment: @DRW02 yeah like I suspected... only the keyframes are being transmitted. I am not sure right now how to fix this, have you tried on other browsers? Does it only happen with Opera?  
I am not sure it changes anything, but I'll take say it anywway, you never know: make sure you call `addStream()` before you call either `setLocalDescription()` or `setRemoteDescription()`. I noticed it messed things up, but I'm not sure it solves your problem. I'd like you to try your code on chromium and firefox and tell us if the problem persists.  
Hope I could help

Comment: @DRW02 have you solved this problem? I have same problem, but on iOS version of the library. Stream on remote device just stops... But on my local device frames are rendered as normal.